# Get a Value from SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table in my SQLite Database:

Table name: Users

```
____________________________________
|IdUser(PK)|User    | Tags |Password|
|20        |Gabriel |Low   |Cat123  |
```

I need the Value "Tags" in a String for Eclipse/Android

I have a select query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = 20 ORDER BY UserID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should operate something like this

```
Cursor c = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE IdUser = 20 ORDER BY IdUser", null);

while (c.moveToNext()) {
     //Sample operation with the Database
     if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("IdUser"))!=null) { 
           //Do something 
     }
}

c.close();
```